# Whats wrong with my roll of film?

Tags: troubleshooting, film, fujifilm

It feels crimped & is torn. Im terrified that all the "wonderful" shots i took are now destroyed... In addition, as my roll was being rewinded into its canister automatically after finishing the last shot.. It did not get sucked into the leader all the way . Can anyone elaborate or assure me if my photos are okay? [image]

I hope you can see the tiny tear & how it is crimped up

Comment: You appear to be having a number of problems with your camera and film.  I would suggest taking this into a camera store that has a repair department (sufficiently knowledgeable people - local drug store does not count) and look at both the film, how it is being loaded, and how it is rewinding to make sure everything is working properly.  There is only so much that one can do and diagnose by looking at pictures.

Comment: Not sure if it's pretty much the same question as [the OP's previous question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56644/my-roll-of-film-didnt-rewind-inside-all-the-way) or if they're just closely related.

Comment: It is the same roll but i have 2 questions. This question is if it matters if my roll was slightly torn at the square holes ...

Comment: With what kind of camera did you shoot this film?

Comment: I used a konica minolta zoom 160c

Answer (score 2):

Your camera has a problem, but dealing with the film is fairly easy. You need to take it to  a pro lab (again, the drugstore does not count. You want something in the industrial part of town) that can load their machine manually. Opening a 35mm film canister takes 5 seconds (I used to use a bottle opener, or you can just peel it open by hand) but you need a changing bag, a transfer box and a bit of practice.

Expect to pay a bit more for the service.